# 0 Not working in currency type input

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am taking the input in form of currency like 54 gets converted to 0.54,but When I am trying to enter 100, I get out as 0.1 only.The code is not working for `0`.  You cannot enter value as `100.00` .The code I am using is

```
 (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)transactionAmount shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range
replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

    NSString *substring = transactionAmount.text;
    substring = [substring stringByAppendingString:string];
    NSLog(@"Text : %@",substring);

    NSString *cleanCentString = [[transactionAmount.text
                                  componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                                  [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]]
                                 componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    // Parse final integer value
    NSInteger centAmount = cleanCentString.integerValue;
    // Check the user input
    if (string.length > 0)
    {
        // Digit added
        centAmount = centAmount * 10 + string.integerValue;
    }
    else
    {
        // Digit deleted
        centAmount = centAmount / 10;
    }
    // Update call amount value
    NSNumber *amount = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:(float)centAmount / 100.0f];
    // Write amount with currency symbols to the textfield
    NSNumberFormatter *_currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    // [_currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    [_currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    [_currencyFormatter setCurrencyCode:@"USD"];
    [_currencyFormatter setNegativeFormat:@"-¤#,##0.00"];
    self.transactionAmount.text = [_currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:amount];
  //  [self SetMainMessage:customTipsValue.text];


    return NO;
}
```

Comment: What's supposed to happen in that if-else loop? Aren't you changing centAmount before you calculate amount? Which would maybe explain why you're seeing a result that's 1000th the original instead of 100th?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of your initial "string cleaning" is wrong and your number formatter isn't correct. It should be something like this:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)transactionAmount shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSString *substring = transactionAmount.text;
    substring = [substring stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    NSLog(@"New Text : %@",substring);

    NSString *cleanCentString = [[substring
                              componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                              [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]]
                             componentsJoinedByString:@""];

    // Parse final integer value
    NSInteger centAmount = cleanCentString.integerValue;

    // Update call amount value
    NSNumber *amount = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:centAmount / 100.0f];

    // NOTE: make this an instance variable and set it up just once
    // Write amount with currency symbols to the textfield
    NSNumberFormatter *_currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [_currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    [_currencyFormatter setCurrencyCode:@"USD"];
    [_currencyFormatter setNegativeFormat:@"-¤#,##0.00"];

    self.transactionAmount.text = [_currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:amount];

    return NO;
}
```

If, for some reason, you want to use Decimal format instead of Currency format, make sure you set the minimum and maximum fraction digits (decimal places) to 2.

Do you really want to hardcode USD? What about people using the app in other countries?

Your original string cleaning didn't properly support a user using cut, copy, or paste. It also used the wrong text to create `cleanCentString`.

Answer (score 1):

What I understood is

If entered value is 0, you want 0.

If entered value is between 1 and 99, you want 0.01 to 0.99.

If entered value is 1 or more, you want 1.00, like wise.

Why don't you get straight as `float requiredCurrency=inputCurrency/100.0f;`

Comment: `NSNumber *amount = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:(float)centAmount / 100.0f];` The line you have mentioned is also added to the code. Please check the snippet